# How to implement advanced search by converting input object to QueryExpression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011

The client will pass in SomeObject to a controller:

```
    [Route("Search", Name = "AdvancedSearch")]
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Entity> AdvancedSearch()
    {
        var search = searchService.Search([FromBody] SomeObject);
        return search;
    }
```

Where SomeObject can be as simple as:

```
public class SomeObject
{pulic int myInt{get;set;}
```

or as complicated as:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
    public string BillingLocationId { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string MsagId { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Apartment { get; set; }
    public string TaxAreaName { get; set; }
    public Guid RegionId { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BillingTaxAreaId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPending { get; set; }
}
```

**How can I parse the object and create a QueryExpression or FetchExpression out of it?**

I would like to make this code generic, so that we can remove boiler plate code such as this that creates the QueryExpression, but in an extremely custom/non-reusable way:

```
     public List<abservicelocation> Search(ServiceLocation serviceLocation, string searchBy)
        {
            // save the input values
            var addressCriteria = serviceLocation.Name.Trim();
            var cityCriteria = serviceLocation.City.Trim();
            var stateCriteria = serviceLocation.State.Trim();

            // replace * for wildcard searching
            addressCriteria = addressCriteria.Replace("*", string.Empty);

            var locationQuery = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = abservicelocation.EntityLogicalName,
                NoLock = true,
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
                Distinct = true,
                Criteria = new FilterExpression()
            };

            //Can't use .Contains here due to the following SQL error:
            /*"Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view because it is not full-text indexed."*/
            locationQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("abname", ConditionOperator.Like, "%" + addressCriteria + "%");
            locationQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("abcity", ConditionOperator.Equal, cityCriteria);
            locationQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("abstateorprovince", ConditionOperator.Equal, stateCriteria);
            //Added this criteria in the change from using address line 1 to abname to avoid PO BOXES and Rural Routes
            locationQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("abname", ConditionOperator.NotNull);

            if (serviceLocation.PostalCode != "null" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceLocation.PostalCode))
            {
                locationQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("abpostalcodefull", ConditionOperator.Like, "%" + serviceLocation.PostalCode + "%");
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceLocation.Apartment))
            {
                locationQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("abapartment", ConditionOperator.Like, "%" + serviceLocation.Apartment + "%");
            }

            locationQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("abmasterlocationid", ConditionOperator.NotNull);

            var regionLink = new LinkEntity
            {
                LinkFromEntityName = abservicelocation.EntityLogicalName,
                LinkToEntityName = "abcommonregion",
                LinkFromAttributeName = "abregionid",
                LinkToAttributeName = "abcommonregionid",
                JoinOperator = JoinOperator.LeftOuter,
                Columns = new ColumnSet("abname"),
                EntityAlias = "abregion"
            };
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make some basic assumptions and try to tackle the simple problem, and then talk about some of the specifics of the more difficult problems.

Let's make some assumptions

1. The properties of `SomeObject` are a 1:1 naming convention to the CRM Entity
2. The SomeObject has an "EntityLogicalName" field that can be used to determine the entity to be queried.
3. We are only interested in doing equality comparisons, no Likes, LessThans, or NotNulls
4. We are always going to return all columns (which has a bad result on performance)
5. We are only concerned with querying a single entity at a time.  No Joins.

Given these rather restrictive constraints, how could we implement this?  You've already have the code for instantiating the `QueryExpression`, so I'll skip that since having the EntityLogicalName in the `SomeObject` makes things pretty simple.

So how do we handle adding the condition Expressions?  You can use reflection to lookup all the properties of the `SomeObject`.  The `PropertyInfo` contains the name and value of the property, and so you can use this to build the condition expression, lower casing the property name, and adding an Equals condition with the value of the property.

That will work, but now the problem is, you will have queries that are more complicated than that, that break some of our assumptions.  Lets look at the assumptions and what is required to relax each one:

**1. The properties of `SomeObject` are a 1:1 naming convention to the CRM Entity**
You have a couple options if this isn't the case.  You could add property attributes that contain the actual logical name of the property to be queried, or, have a mapping that is passed in, that maps the `SomeObject` properties to their CRM logical names.

**2. The SomeObject has an "EntityLogicalName" field that can be used to determine the entity to be queried.**  Either you need a property that contains the value, or a Class level Attribute, or another parameter that you pass into the service, in addition to `SomeObject`

** 3. We are only interested in doing equality comparisons, no Likes, LessThans, or NotNulls** This becomes a little more difficult to deal with, like how do you pass the values of an `in` statement in?  But again, you could use Property Attributes to determine the name of the condional operations to use, or a dictionary of properties and they operations to use.

**4. We are always going to return all columns (which has a bad result on performance)**  You'll have to pass in the columns to be returned in a standard property, or pass in an additional parameter besides `SomeObject` to your service.

**5. We are only concerned with querying a single entity at a time. No Joins.**
This one becomes exceedingly complicated.  You could add properties that contains objects themselves, rather than primitive values so `SomeObject.Contact.FirstName`  but that doesn't account for the type of join.  And even more complicated is how to account for criteria that should be added to the join, and not to the uppermost where when dealing with outer join queries.

At this point in time I would seriously question the cost benefit of trying to implement such a system.  This is exactly why `QueryExpressions` and `FetchXml` were created, so someone could define a query on the client side and execute it on the server side (not entirely sure why TSQL wasn't used instead, but that's a different issue entirely).  CRM has a limited set of endpoints that can be used to query it, some how, in some way shape or form, you'll have to translate your `SomeObject` into that.